# Jquery, how to select an element by its first position value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In html:

```
<tr data-s=""></tr>
<tr data-s="1"></tr>
<tr data-s="2 1"></tr>
<tr data-s="3 2 1"></tr>
```

I'm trying to build a selector in order to get the trs by the value of the first position of data-s attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "first position"? Do you mean something like, "the first span of non-whitespace characters in the value"?

Comment: Is this what you are asking: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: So by way of example, if your input is "2" you want to select just the third one? Or...? Please clarify.

Comment: I think the OP means when he choses '3' he want the last `tr`, because it's `data-s` attribute starts with 3. Or what @nnnnnn meant.

Comment: Do you want to get value of first column value on tr click ?

Comment: Hi all. First of all thanks for your responses. I'm trying to get the trs that their first value in data-s is 3, or 2 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the element by first position of data-s attribute as far as I understood.

```
$('[data-s^="3 "]');
```

Or if you want to get first position of data-s attribute's value, you can do this;

```
$('[data-s]').data('s').split(' ')[0];
```

There is [a plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/o7oAGWABYaCHnjtxjmjO?p=preview) for you.

Comment: Related documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split(" ")[0]` to get first value of data-s attribute

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-s").split(" ")[0])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-s=""></tr>
<tr data-s="1"></tr>
<tr data-s="2 1"></tr>
<tr data-s="3 2 1"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on jQuery.filter function:

```js
$(function () {
  var elements = $('table tr').filter(function(index, element) {
    return this.getAttribute('data-s').split(' ')[0] == '1';
  });
  console.log(elements.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr data-s=""></tr>
    <tr data-s="1"></tr>
    <tr data-s="2 1"></tr>
    <tr data-s="3 2 1"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-s]').each(function () {
    var test = $(this).attr('data-s')
    if(test != undefined){
        var firstDataValue = parseInt(test.split(' ')[0]);
        /*run you test case for first value and return back this on success */
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function customFn(elm,sel)
{
  var tmp = $();
  $(elm).each(function(){
    data=$(this).data('s').toString().split(' ')[0];
    if(data.trim()===sel.toString().trim())
     tmp=tmp.add(this);
  });
  return tmp
}

customFn("tr","3");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68x8Leuz/